# Wax around PVC pipe connections

Tags: plumbing, pvc

Has anyone ever encountered wax that was applied around the exterior of PVC plumbing pipe joints?

Our basement has two stacks that have what appears to be the wax you would apply to a toilet flange smeared around a handful of joints/connections:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The house was built in 1983 and we moved in 2 years ago. We recently had our kitchen sink drain back up and while performing the clean out, the plumber smudged one of the brown waxy areas next to a fitting with his finger and water droplets appeared.

Said he hasn’t seen this before and the theory is that perhaps the builders roughed in the plumbing but didn’t use pipe primer/sealant and did this as a shortcut (?).

I will note that was believe this to be the original 40+ year old plumbing and have not noted any other issues aside from this kitchen drain backup.

Comment: Is the stuff soft like wax, or is it hard?  If hard it may be old glue.  It certainly does not look like the pipes have had primer and proper glue on them.  It may be a DIYers use of improper glue.

Comment: That would be a "kludge" and a violation of plumbing code, whihc is not overly fond of kludges.

Comment: Upvoted the question for the sheer horror of it.  Assuming this isn't just a poll, but that when you say "Has anyone seen" you mean "is there some outside chance I can just leave this alone" the answer to *that* question is "No.  Absolutely not, Fix it.  Urgently".

Comment: Grab one of those wyes and try to twist the stack.  If it's properly welded it shouldn't rotate at all.